# Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader error

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

First of all i should say that i am new to Maven, even thought i dont think that Maven has to do with this error. I am using Eclipse 4.2.1 with m2e
I have this code that i got from the [ckan4j](https://github.com/sciamlab/ckan4j) developer

```
Client c = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
WebTarget wt = c.target("192.168.1.2/action").path("resource_update");
Builder b = wt.request();
b.header("authorization", "fa0499d1-ffda-4590-82b3-4afdb9c91576");
FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("upload", new File("/home/ilias/Downloads/OdtUtils.java"));
FormDataMultiPart multipart = (FormDataMultiPart) new FormDataMultiPart().field("id","test2").bodyPart(filePart);
String response_string = b.post(Entity.entity(multipart, multipart.getMediaType())).readEntity(String.class);       
System.out.println(response_string);
```

this is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ckanTest2</groupId>
  <artifactId>ckanConn2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>CkanConnectTest</name>     

   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am not 100% sure about the dependencies, but i was just searching for the error i was getting while compiling and added the results here, till i got no errors.
Now when i build maven (using `generate-sources`) i get this

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".  
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:  
See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.  
[INFO] Scanning for projects...   
[INFO]            
[INFO]-----------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] Building CkanConnectTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS  
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------    [INFO] Total time: 0.298s  
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 24 19:50:57 EEST 2015  
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/58M  
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

which even thought it is complaining about the logger, i am not so eager to solve right now. other than that it seems to be building all right.

When trying to execute the java file i get this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader   
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1371)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1310)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1232)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:97)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.util.FeatureContextDelegate.register(FeatureContextDelegate.java:37)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.util.FeatureContextDelegate.register(FeatureContextDelegate.java:12)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature.configure(MultiPartFeature.java:65)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1673)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1310)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1232)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.register(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:361)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.register(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:48)
    at cKanTest.CkanAlpha.main(CkanAlpha.java:17)  

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find a public constructor for provider class  
  org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createConstructorInjector(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2184)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2173)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.addMessageBodyReader(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:748)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1366)
    ... 14 more
```

*I used the xml tag just to make the xml code more readable*

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Blueriver I honestly do not remember! This was a testing application, in order to see how the API was working (for ckan). i got the API working though. what is ur problem? maybe i might be able to help

Comment: thanks for the offer. I'm quite new at my work and this technology, so I went to the most knowledgeable guy in my team and after a couple of hours he got it to work. I think our problem was that we were declaring twice: once in the framework and once in the .war. In the end we annotated the EJB dependencies as provided, so we could generate the .war and not get an odd dependency conflict which apparently resulted in our error. Or something like that. Again, thanks for your offer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem caused by the combination of RestEasy and Jersey (org.glassfish.jersey.media):

```
ResteasyProviderFactory factory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers.class, factory);
```

Another hint is to use the dependency jersey-media-multipart instead of jersey-multipart